# forms_for_model() and forms_for_instance() are deprecated how do I use ModelForm subclass Instead?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

***models.py***

```
class Person(models.Model):

    userID = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField('name', max_length=200)
    birthday = models.DateField('Birthday',blank=True,null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=gender_list)
    email = models.EmailField('Email', max_length=100,unique=True)
    favoriteURL = models.URLField('myURL')  
    desc = models.TextField('Desc', max_length=500,null=True)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True)
    blogs = models.ManyToManyField(Blog, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.name)
```

***views.py***

```
def person_form(request, pID='0'):

    #default
    **PersonForm = forms.form_for_model(Person)** my query
    f = PersonForm()
    message = 'Unknown Request'
    p = get_object_or_404(Person, pk=pID)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        **PersonForm = forms.form_for_instance(p)** my query
        message = 'Editing person %s ' % p.name
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST['submit'] == 'update':
            message = 'Update Request for %s. ' % p.name
            **PersonForm = forms.form_for_instance(p)** my query
            if f.is_valid():
                message += 'Valid.'
            else:
                message += 'Invalid.'
    return render_to_response('People/person_form.html', locals())
```

I tried: `PersonForm = ModelForm(model=Person)` but it throws `__init__() got unexpected kewyword argument 'model'`. I'm new in Python and I use Django in 24 hours textbook it seems like most of the methods are deprecated. Any idea how can I can replace forms_for_model() with ModelForm()?

Answer (score 0):

Django in 24 hours is really outdated now.

Consider switching to [djangobook v2.0](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/) - it's up to date and really great. And official docs on [modelforms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/)

[Here](http://mirobetm.blogspot.com/2008/03/django-modelform-replacement-for.html) is small comparison of old and newforms.

Answer (score 0):

[The docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/) explain this fully.